# Using external js libraries in sapui5

Tags: javascript, jquery, sapui5

So I'm trying to inlcude an external .js file in my SAPUI5 Controller.

```
    jQuery.sap.includeScript("externalLibrary.min.js", 
    function() {
        //initalizing objects from library
    });
```

However, the callback which should be called once the script is loaded, never gets called. The error message it gives me is:

> "externalLibrary.min.js:16 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'Constructor' of undefined"

Whats another way I could do this? I was looking into jQuery.sap.registerModulePath() and jQuery.sap.registerResourcePath() but couldn't find a good example of the use of these nor an explaination of the difference between the two online.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Which library are you trying to include...maybe that library references another library or dependecy.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Got it! For future reference, it works to load the files from the index html like so:

```
 <script src="library.js"></script>
```

The main problem was that I was trying to include external dependencies which also contained jQuery. So, I had to remove that from the file and now it's working.

Answer (score 4):

You can try `jQuery.sap.includeScript(vUrl, sId?, fnLoadCallback?, fnErrorCallback?)`

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/jQuery.sap.html#.includeScript

in fiori launchpad based app , we use component.js as root , so we don't have index.html to include scripts (if you use XML view instand of HTML view).

try

```
jQuery.sap.includeScript({
    url: "https://maps.googleapis.com...",
    id: "IncludeGoogleMapsScript"
}).then(function() { ... })
```

Not working in portal service , fallback is provided :
[UsingjQuery.sap.includeScript().then() in HCP Firori Launchpad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38967981/usingjquery-sap-includescript-then-in-hcp-firori-launchpad/38973947#38973947)

Comment: Is there a need for the .then()-function? If I read the deefinition of the includeScript() right, then I would put that function into fnLoadCallback and define a fnErrorCallback if needed, right?

Answer (score -1):

You can use jQuery.sap.registerResourcePath('lib', URL) and then jquery.SAP.require('lib.file'). You can do both one after another or register in the init and later require. Does not matter. I don't have an example at hand as I am on a phone but it works. What you need to keep in mind is that this example would load something like URL/file.js so you need to adjust accordingly. The name you give to the lib does not matter.
You can also inject a script tag into the current page ,however, the require will load the external lib synchronously while if you inject a script tag you need to wait until it is loaded with a callback.

PS: the capitalization on those methods is not right