# jQuery.sap.includeScript().then() not working in SCP SAPUI5 app

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori, sap-cloud-platform

I'm trying to include googlemaps in sapui5

```
jQuery.sap.includeScript({
                url: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXX",
                promisify: true
            }).then(function() { ... } )
```

This Promise works fine when I run in SAP Web-IDE Trial, but when I deploy it to hana cloud platform it is not working:

> InterceptService.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: u.indexOf is not a function(…)
>   sap.ushell.cloudServices.interceptor.InterceptService._invokeFilters @ InterceptService.js:1
>
> jQuery.sap.includeScript @ InterceptService.js:1
>
> onAfterRendering @ Worklist.controller.js:37

`InterceptService.js` code fragment that produced this error is

```
{if(u.indexOf('/sap/fiori/../../')>0){u=u.replace('/sap/fiori/../../','/');}
```

I do use **HCP Portal Service** to produce HCP Fiori Launchpad Platform.

How to fix this? What I did wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You don't need to pass `promisify: true`, since it is ignored by UI5

Comment: from experience you will still need to use a callback  "When the API is ready, it will call the function specified using the callback parameter." https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial

Comment: FYI can recommend http://jasper07.secondphase.com.au/openui5-googlemaps/

Comment: Thanks @Jasper_07 I've tried these two ways . But I use xml view , so it is not that convenient to use the way that google recommended( I don't know how to put init function in another module).  And I don't see the necessity to use openui5-googlemaps....I have had enough of xml view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is indeed issue of `InterceptorService`, which does not support the syntax of `includeScript` with object as first argument.

I've forwarded a code of the solution to implementation team of **HCP Portal Service** and it will be fixed in the next release.

So far, you can achieve the same functionality with the following workaround:

```js
new Promise(function(fnResolve, fnReject) {
    jQuery.sap.includeScript(
        "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXX", 
        "mapsScriptId", fnResolve, fnReject
    );
}).then(function() { ... } )
```

*See how UI5 implements it:* https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/rel-1.38/src/sap.ui.core/src/jquery.sap.global.js#L4387-L4389

Comment: Hi Vadim, awesome answer !  Could you please explain more about why 'InterceptorService' will have effect on 'includeScript'? I thought that it is only the broswer that have effect on resolving these functions. Any help or material is welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the InterceptService doesn't support the newest signature of jQuery.sap.includeScript (where parameters are provided in a configuration object instead of as individual arguments) yet.

Midterm, the InterceptService needs to be enhanced / fixed. Short-term, you might fall back to the old signature [jQuery.sap.includeScript(url, id, onload, onerror)](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/jQuery.sap.html#.includeScript). There is unfortunately no way to get a Promise with the old signature.